# attempt to define a geo location attribute [Coords] when another one has been previously defined

Tags: fiware-orion

I have migrated to Orion latest version using docker pull.

I had my service receiving data from an IOTAgent and I had several entities already created in the previous Orion release (0.26). Orion was able to receive the data sent by the IOTAgent.

However after the migration I'm getting this alarm

```
orion_1 | WARNING@10:33:31  AlarmManager.cpp[380]: Raising alarm BadInput myIPADDRESS: attempt to define a geo location attribute [Coords] when another one has been previously defined []
```

This is the JSON I get as response

```
[Wed, 11 May 2016 12:27:52 +0200] ERROR JSON response= :{
  "contextResponses" : [
    {
      "contextElement" : {
        "type" : "STCSensor",
        "isPattern" : "false",
        "id" : "403432100",
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "Serial",
            "type" : "integer",
            "value" : ""
          },
          {
            "name" : "BatteryLevel",
            "type" : "integer",
            "value" : ""
          },
          {
            "name" : "Timestamp",
            "type" : "integer",
            "value" : ""
          },
          {
            "name" : "Latitude",
            "type" : "float",
            "value" : ""
          },
          {
            "name" : "Longitude",
            "type" : "float",
            "value" : ""
          },
          {
            "name" : "Coords",
            "type" : "geo:point",
            "value" : ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode" : {
        "code" : "472",
        "reasonPhrase" : "request parameter is invalid/not allowed",
        "details" : "action: APPEND - entity: [403432100, STCSensor] - offending attribute: Coords - attempt to define a geo location attribute [Coords] when another one has been previously defined []"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Should I delete all my entities and subscriptions?

Mongodb has not been updated, still using 2.6

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you edit your questition post to include the output of the following command run on the MongoDB host, please? `echo 'db.entities.find({"_id.id" : "403432100", "_id.type": "STCSensor"}).pretty()' | mongo orion`. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed the issue removing the entity. The entity was recreated with the new notification coming from our IOTAgent and everything now is working well.

Comment: Great to know! Side-note: it is better to use a modern version of MongoDB with Orion, e.g. MongoDB 3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to user report (see comment on the question post), a solution is to re-create the entity (i.e. delete, then create again).

Probably the cause of the problem was in some incoherence in the DB document corresponding to the entity at MongoDB. However, we never know... :)